# Scala: Typed Emptiness?

Tags: dictionary, null, scala-collections, scala-2.8, option-type

I'm wondering if it's possible to give a Type to something "empty" in Scala?

For example, I'm looking for something like `Null[String]` or `Nothing[String]` or `None[String]`.

I'm not looking to use an Option. To be honest, what I'm doing is I have a map:

```
options: Map[String, Any] = Map("id" -> Null, "num" -> Null)
```

That other people will "extend" with:

```
_options: Map[String, Any] = Map("id" -> "Hi", "num" -> 5)
options = options ++ _options
```

And I want to be able to specify what types are suppose to be given in the map.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

no None is just a Object . it may like constant .

Comment: Right. Just Option.empty[String]?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this: val option: Map[String,Any] = Map("id" -> null)

Comment: That's what I have, but it still doesn't give any kind of type to the value.

Comment: you can just write : val option = Map("id" -> null)

Comment: No, I know that. My point is whether I can specify the types of the values.

Comment: (even when they are empty)

Comment: As I know , None just for compatibility java . It is just like a  constant